# JQuery POST request user feedback

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have the form that submits with a jQuery post request. Something like this:

```
$('#foo').submit(function (e) {
    $.post('/api/baz/break', $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (guidString) {
            // manipulate good result
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            // manipulate bad result
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My problem is that on the good result there is no visual feedback to the user to show that a process is completing.

What is the simplest way that I show the user a visual spinner that lets them see that something is going on? Since the page doesn't reload because the promise hasn't been resolved.

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this, from showing a message on the page, to showing a short living modal, not to mention using a busy indicator like a spinner or the like during processing.  This question in that regards is too broad.

Comment: Ok let me be specific i will edit this

Comment: @Taplar I like the approach that you mentioned with the physical spinner, since the page doesn't send a reload or anything. But how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: `$('#spinner').show();` on start and `$('#spinner').hide()` on success or error.

Comment: Where in the function would be an `on-start`? To my understanding there is only an on success and on error path to the promise.

Comment: @FelixKling if you can post your recommendation as a solution indicating how it works I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this on my own. I made a css loader component following the guidelines from w3schools linked here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

I customized mine like so:

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader {
  /*Warning- this class must be attached to a div to work properly, can attach and remove dynamically with javascript for async operations*/
  border-top: 1em solid #106A3A;
  border-right: 1em solid #E58242;
  border-bottom: 1em solid #91D3EF;
  border-left: 1em solid #7F3E97;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 7.5em;
  height: 7.5em;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='loader'></div>
```

So in the js I just added the component in the javascript layer like so:

```
$('#foo').submit(function (e) {
    $('#foo').toggle();
    $('fooParent').append('<div class="loader"></div>');
    $.post('/api/baz/break', $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (guidString) {
            // manipulate good result
            $('#foo').toggle();
            $('loader').remove();
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            // manipulate bad result
            $('#foo').toggle();
            $('loader').remove();
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```